# How to have RoleEntryPoint.OnStop() called in Azure Compute Emulator?

Tags: windows, debugging, azure, cloud, azure-web-roles

I'm testing a trivial web role under Azure Compute Emulator and have overridden `OnStart()`, `Run()` and `OnStop()` methods in my class that derives from `RoleEntryPoint`.

`OnStart()` and `Run()` are called but `OnStop()` is not - I will either press "Stop debugging" in Visual Studio or close the browser window and the role will be terminated, but `OnStop()` is never called.  I've checked - the `override` keyword is present in `OnStop()` definition.

That's not very convenient - it means I can't test my `OnStop()` outside a live cloud.

Can I somehow make Compute Emulator call `OnStop()` in my role?

Comment: As of Nov 2012, you must use RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect (but I'm not sure), that if you open the compute emulator UI and "stop" the deployment there, OnStop() should be called.

Comment: This no longer works. Calling RoleEnvironment.RequestRecycle();  works

Comment: As far as I can tell this is working again, though the options are "Suspend" or "Restart" now in the emulator UI.

Comment: Far from perfect design decision. If VS can indicate to fabric to abort when VS debugger is stopping, emulator should raise OnStop... if you happen to spawn off processes in your role, those will not be terminated and become ghosts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use csrun to update the configuration of a running deployment. When you give the command the instance will call the OnStop() method.

To update the ServiceConfigure:

- Open the Azure SDK bin folder through the command line
- Issue the command csrun.exe /update:{Deployment ID, just the number};{Path of the cscfg file}

In my Compute Emulator it would be:

- csrun.exe /update:252;"D:\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSM\CSC\bin\Debug\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg"

Answer (score 1):

If you intentionally exit from the Run() method, I believe OnStop() should be called.

Comment: That works, but requires editing code and also the role neither restarts not terminates after that.